# Is this an outdoor ground rod?

Tags: electrical, grounding

This is outside my house. I can't find any wires going to it. Is this a ground rod? Is it safe to run new ground wire from the house to it? Due to the rust, should I remove it and install a new 8ft copper ground rod?

There is another active ground rod on the other side of the house.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a ground rod to me. But I wouldn't reuse it, because you don't know the condition of it. A new one will cost around $20 or so and the inspector can't argue with it. An old one? They might make you pull it up and then likely say "looks corroded, better replace it".